# Не понимаю назначение virtual

Tags: c++

На протяжении всего изучения языка никак не могу понять и усвоить назначение ключевого слова `virtual`

Заранее извиняюсь за сей бред что возможно мог сморозить,**если лень читать то сразу посмотрите на предпоследнее предложение**)

Из всяких форумов я вырыл и запомнил следующее, о этом волшебном слове:

1. **Когда что-то принимает различные формы,но тем не менее продолжает свою суть.**  Попробую объяснить просто. Думаю имеется ввиду что у меня есть какая-то там функция `Draw` класса `Base` рисующая круг,тут я сделал её виртуальной,создал новый класс `Base2` с такой же функцией `Draw`,наследовал базовый класс с кругом и после типо могу вызывать `Base b1=new Base();` ну и `Base2 b2=new Base();`  а дальше вызывать нужное рисование. Но уже тут,я не понимаю смысла. Окей,я видел рассуждения на каком-то форуме что-то типо:

> Зачем это вам нужно? Нужно что бы постоянно не делать приведение к каждому классу(`пытался на память повторить код,но лучше не буду,а то будет просто смех какой-то`)

*Но ведь разве мне сложно делать приведение каждого? Да нет вроде,вызывать топорно тоже не сложно.*

2. **Одновременно является носителем многих форм.** Дальше был пример типо,у нас есть алмаз и есть графит,оба из углерода. Типо углерод принимает разные формы,он у нас тут виртуален. Окей,ну тут +- понятно,что в таком случае поставить виртуальность(поставить слово которое ставят все без объяснения)

*Опять же,пункт описания для определения нужно ли ставить ключевое слово. Но зачем? не понятно.*

Я не знаю что и написать.Из написанного мной же выше,я не могу прийти к выводу зачем мне использовать `virtual` и что это значит. Везде его вижу,аж стыдна,что я один такой не понимаю.

Помогите разобраться в этом слове, пожалуйста Х) я даже не столько синтаксис не понимаю,сколько **смысл и преимущества в использовании**

*P.s. только пожалуйста,пишите простыми ответами,а то часто ответ вроде есть,но что бы его понять нужно загуглить и просидеть пол дня.*

Comment: Дело в том, что приведение к классу-наследнику каждый раз может быть просто невозможно, так как код, вызывающий функцию, не в курсе о существовании каких-то там наследников, он работает только со ссылкой на экземпляр базового класса.

Comment: "Но ведь разве мне сложно делать приведение каждого? Да нет вроде,вызывать топорно тоже не сложно." и придется где то хранить тип, и городить if-else или switch-case для обработки. А потом появляется ещё один наследник...

Comment: Всё ООП в `C++` имитируется средствами `С` - структурами, ссылками на функции, приведениями. Можно (до некоторой степени) считать что `C++` ООП - синтаксический сахар, чтобы было удобнее работать с наследованием.

Comment: @KoVadim окей,хранить где-то? предположим я создам макрос который присоединяет к названию Base номер, а классы будут пронумерованы и всё в цикл. То есть по сути тоже самое что и было,окей,не тоже самое. Лишние только приведение и макрос. Всё равно не понимаю смысла

Comment: *"смысл и преимущества в использовании"* Вот представьте. Вы делаете игру, у вас есть `class Monster { virtual void Attack() {} };`, и массив указателей на него. Есть классы, которые от него наследуются и переопределяют функцию. Вы делаете цикл по массиву и делаете `array[i]->Attack();`. Без виртуальности это не сработает. Вручную кастовать элементы - не прокатит.

Comment: Слово virtual используется в функциях за тем, что бы переопределить именно эту функцию используя override, для того что бы обработчики базового класса могли вызвать предопределенную функцию, которая может быть по умолчанию пустой. Если вы не будете пользоваться этим механизмом то будет просто две отдельные не связанные друг с другом ф-ции хоть и с одинаковым именем. Оно?

Comment: @Bobs1970 - и изобретете виртуальность по новому. Так иногда делают. Но вот только зачем? компилятор умеет уже. Плюс, в некоторых случаях компилятор может делать "развиртуализацию", когда ему понятен тип (а компилятор в этом плане значительно лучше среднестатистического джуна) и ускорить код.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat то есть,весь смысл слова заключается в том что оно убирает каст если множество обращений?

Comment: Да, как уже написали, это все можно сделать на голом С, только писанины больше, и возможно будет соптимизировано компилятором хуже. Это про любую фичу С++ можно сказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим пример.

Некий разработчик создает библиотеку, с помощью которой, можно написать свою игру.
Идея в том, чтобы можно было задать определения своих игровых объектов, их поведение, то как они выглядят в виде классов, слинковать с библиотекой, запустить код типа:

```
Game game = new Game();

game.addGameObject(new Hero());
game.addGameObject(new Enemy1());
game.addGameObject(new Enemy2());

game.run();
```

`Game` внутри себя хранит вектор игровых объектов, а `run` (среди прочего) вызывает код для рисования всех игровых объектов типа такого:

```
void Game::drawAllGameObjects() {
   ...
   for (vector<GameObject*>::iterator it = gameObjects.begin(); it != 
gameObjects.end(); it++) {
      (*it)->draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

Тут классы `Hero` и `Enemy1` - создаются разработчиком игры, про них разработчик библиотеки ничего не знает. Он написал метод `run` и класс `GameObject` предполагая, что разработчик игры для каждого игрового объекта создаст класс-наследник от `GameObject` и напишет реализацию `draw`. Она будет рисовать используя примитивы типа `drawPixel`, `drawLine` и `copyBitmap` игровой объект.

Из библиотеки:

```
struct GameObject {
   virtual void draw(Canvas* canvas) {
   }
};
```

Из программы:

```
struct Hero : GameObject {
   void draw(Canvas* canvas) override { // тут ключевое слово virtual необязательно
      ...
   }
};
```

При этом реализацию библиотеки, в частности метод `drawAllObjects` разработчик библиотеки скомпилирует заранее и будет распостранять в виде бинарного файла (т.е. без исходного кода).

Для того, чтобы в функции `drawAllObjects` был вызван нужный метод (т.е. для `Hero` метод `Hero::draw`, а для `Enemy1` - `Enemy1::draw`), о которых разработчик библиотеки ничего не знает, и нужно объявить метод `GameObject::draw` как `virtual`. В этом случае компилятор создаст правильный код для вызова метода из конкретного объекта, который будет доступен только во время выполнения (грубо - это будет косвенный вызов метода, т.е. адрес метода не прошит в коде, а берется из таблицы, которая хранится в конкретном объекте).

Если нет `virtual`, то в месте вызова `draw` компилятором будет вставлен вызов метода `GameObject::draw` не зависимо от типа объекта в `it` и эта задумка с `drawAllGameObject` не будет работать.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение,т.к. я не знаю как должно быть. Возьмём Ваш пример,получается мы создали класс с новым персонажем и что бы его нарисовать нам нужно внутри нашего нового класса поставить `virtual` и добавить наследование от какого-то там базового класса разработчика. **поправьте меня если я ошибся выше** и `vitrual` у нас должно быть получается только в базовом классе,разработчика? или должно быть и у нас и у разработчика?

Comment: И в итоге получается. Преимуществом будет у нас как мне писали в комментах, отсутствие каста и в случае как написали Вы,для возможности добавить  в игру от разраба свой метод. Т.е. не имея исходников,но зная наследуемый класс и примерно представляя какой метод отвечает за рисование,мы можем просто клипать моды и отрисовывать все функции с помощью виртуальной функции `draw` добавленной разрабом

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Синтаксически virtual нужно только на базовом классе.

Comment: @Bobs1970 В потомке `virtual` появляется автоматически (на тех функциях, которые в родителе виртуальные), поэтому писать его самому не обязательно. Но рекомендуется писать `override`.

Comment: Так тут каст никак не сделать, мы заранее не знаем тип объекта. А даже если будем знать (это наша библиотека), делать такой общий код зависимым от всех наследников плохо, ненужная связность.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ок,ок,буду знать,не думал что переопределение можно добавить. Кстати неплохая такая подсказка!

Comment: я знаю один случай, когда у человека была програма визуализатор склада и у него было 3 типа объекта - человек, ящик и погрузчик. Изначально был енум на это дело и в коде постоянно погрузчики катались на ящиках. Но потом он сделал один базовый класс и три наследника и после этого куда то пропало большое кол-во багов, куча if/switch...

Comment: @KoVadim Немного стало яснее кстати,не думал что это слово даёт такой эффект. Просто читал много статей и форумов,в одном из ресурсов было написано _избегайте `vitrual` т.к. создаёт дополнительные ссылки и долгое обращение к ним_

Comment: виртуальный вызов может быть не таким быстрым, как "прямой". И если это код, который требовательный к быстродействию, то да, возможно и нужно подумать хорошо. Но в большинстве случаев виртуальный вызов может быть быстрее самопального if. Но опять же, все нужно бенчмаркать.

Comment: @KoVadim запомню,спасибо!